# Why isn't there space between my menu items?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a test site to get better at html and CSS. I found a design and started to try to make that design right now I have this:

[image: site right now]

But as you can see the navbar items are way too close to each other and for some reason the icon wont show up.

can someone explain to me why the navbar items wont get space between each other and why my icon is not showing up? Thanks in advance.

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 1rem;
}

nav .logo {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

nav li a {
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav class='container'>
  <div class='logo'><i class="fa-solid fa-otter"></i>Sea otters</div>
  
  <ul>
    <li a href='#'>Home</li>
    <li a href='#'>Species</li>
    <li a href='#'>Habitat</li>
    <li a href='#'>Behavior</li>
    <li a href='#' class='highlight'>Ecology</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've merged your list item and anchor element markup. They're separate elements and need separate tags.

```
<li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<nav class='container'>
   <div class='logo'><i class="fa-solid fa-otter"></i>Sea otters</div>  
      <ul>
         <li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
         <li><a href='#'>Species</a></li>
         <li><a href='#'>Habitat</a></li>
         <li><a href='#'>Behavior</a></li>
         <li><a href='#' class='highlight'>Ecology</a></li>
     </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome. Some explanation is expected on SO. See [answer].